# Trouble moving from Drive to Cloud SQL in Google AppMaker

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

I have an AppMaker app that uses Drive tables.  However I need to move to Cloud SQL, so I followed the steps here: [Connect AppMaker to Google SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679881/connect-appmaker-to-google-sql)

I created the Clould SQL (PostgreSQL) instance and database fine, then created the same tables in Cloud as I was using in Drive (Well, almost, I could not have a table named User).

When I went to create the Model in AppMaker, it spent a lot of time spinning, then said "Failed to load models for Google Cloud SQL."  And then, strangely, it said Refresh Required.

I thought this was a fluke but when I tried again I got the exact same error messages.  Any idea what is going on?  Is there any chance it is failing because I still have the Drive tables with the same names as the Cloud SQL tables?

Thanks for any tips or pointers.

Comment: It seems like App Maker is having some troubles to scan the DB and detect your models. What kind of Cloud SQL DB are you using? Google Cloud SQL supports both MySQL and PostgreSQL engines, however App Maker only supports MySQL right now. Regards,
Julian.-

Comment: Oh, did not know App Maker did not support PostgreSQL, that is the issue.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Maker does not currently support PostreSQL.